# .htaccess configuration to multiple parameters and files redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this simple .htaccess file `RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z:_-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1` so I can make http://mywebsite.com/stuff and stuff becomes a `GET variable`. I want to extend it's functionalities to make it like `index.php?page=$2&page2=$3...` indefinitely, for things like this http://mywebsite.com/stuff/is/cool still work.

The other problem is that, when I enter in the URL http://mywebsite.com/stuff/ the HTML seems to think it's at the `stuff` folder, so it won't load the files (css, images, etc.), how to solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can process url using PHP
for example let us say your script entry will be index.php
at this file just handle url like that

```
$pages = $_GET['page'];
$extracted_p = explode ("/",$pages);
//and foreach extracted pages to decide what you want with it
```

second part , you need to set base url variable and put inside html base tag
at the most header of your script

i.e

```
$base_url = "http://localhost/myscript/";
```

in html

```
<base href="<?php echo $base_url?>" />
```

and that's all

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating things. Just put this in your `.htaccess`:

```
FallbackResource index.php
```

It will ensure all requests that do not point to an existing file will be handled by `index.php` in the root folder. Then in that file do:

```
$path = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'));
```

And easily parse the `$path` from there, for example:

```
if(!count($path))
  RenderHomepage();
elseif($path[0] == 'blog')
  RenderBlog();
else
{
  header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
  die('This page does not exist');
}
```

As for your other problem, that's logical from the browser's perspective - it doesn't see your internal structure, so it's just doing folder logic according to the URLs it **can** see. This is why you must never use relative paths, just specify your assets root-based as being in `/static/mystyles.css` for instance and they will always resolve fine.

Comment: Seems like an awesome solution, but the `FallbackResource index.php` doesn't seem to work without the index.php file at the end of the page, and I didn't want that. When I put this into a webfolder like http://mysite.com/potatoes, it doesn't work. It will only work like this: http://mysite.com/potatoes/index.php or this: http://mysite.com/potatoes/index.php/other/folders. How to make it work like http://mysite.com/potatoes/other/folders?

Comment: That is [exactly how `FallbackResource` works](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource). If it doesn't you have some other junk in the `.htaccess` that is obstructing it. This should be the only line in there.

Comment: Strange... This is the only line at the .htaccess file. 

Here, it'll only work with the index.php indication at the end. I tried `FallbackResource index.php` and `FallbackResource /index.php`, like in the example and both didn't work properly with the subfolders without the index.php indication.

Comment: `FallbackResource /potatoes/index.php` almost worked. It works if I do this: http://mysite.com/potatoes/other, but won't work only with http://mysite.com/potatoes/. It returns me a javascript console error: `Failed to load resource http://mysite.com/potato/` (while the page still displays but no javascript will work)

Comment: I think the problem is in the / at the end of the URL, but dunno how to solve it

Comment: Check your vhost definition for strange RewriteRules, and remove them all if they're there.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Is `FallbackResource` a replacement for the typical `RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [L]` directive?  Is this Apache 2, without a module?

Comment: Yes it is, and yes it is [native `mod_dir` behaviour](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) (which is installed by default since it also contains for example the `DirectoryIndex` directive). It was [introduced in Apache 2.2.16](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource).

Comment: Removed all the rules and the problem remains.

Comment: I tried to use @landons method, but this won't allow my to access the directories of the website, like `/images` or `/css`

Comment: No because you'd need 2 `RewriteCond` lines too to exclude existing files and directories. I have no clue what's going wrong though, this setup just works as it is, we have released a ton of websites using this approach for fancy URLs. It's ***something*** on your end, I can't see what without a crystal ball though.